# Renaming all htaccess file inside a project directory recursively

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I need to rename all .htaccess file inside the folder home/admin/projects/website to .oldhtaccess, what's the best way to do this in bash? It needs to be done in every folder recursively.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find home/admin/projects/website -depth -name "*.htaccess" -exec sh -c 'f="{}"; mv -- "$f" "${f%.htaccess}.oldhtaccess"' \;
```

Find is a method for recursive search. You can also use `grep -r`.

`mv file1.txt file2.txt` >>> changes the file name

Additional resources:

https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-rename-files-in-linux/

[https://phoenixnap.com/kb/rename-file-linux#:~:text=Rename%20a%20Single%20File%20with%20the%20mv%20Command,mv%20%5Boptions%5D%20%5Bcurrent%20file%20name%5D%20%5Bnew%20file%20name%5D](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/rename-file-linux#:%7E:text=Rename%20a%20Single%20File%20with%20the%20mv%20Command,mv%20%5Boptions%5D%20%5Bcurrent%20file%20name%5D%20%5Bnew%20file%20name%5D)

[https://easierwithpractice.com/is-linux-find-command-recursive/#:~:text=Try%20any%20one%20of%20the%20following%20command%3A%20ls,command%20to%20see%20recursive%20directory%20listing%20in%20Linux](https://easierwithpractice.com/is-linux-find-command-recursive/#:%7E:text=Try%20any%20one%20of%20the%20following%20command%3A%20ls,command%20to%20see%20recursive%20directory%20listing%20in%20Linux).

Good luck working it out!

Comment: find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: It works in my ubuntu VM. Tested by turning example.txt into example.html. Maybe you got the directory in a wrong syntax? (actually plausible if u ctrl + C ctrl + V'd my solution)